# iText7 working with certificates using PKCS7

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm migrating from iText 5.5.5 to iText 7.0.2 and I noticed that class com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7 which I use to work with certificates and signatures is gone. Is there equivalent of the class in iText7 or has it been completley reworked? If so, where did the functionality moved?

Comment: It's still there >.>, package is com.itextpdf.signatures

Comment: You'll find the iText 7 versions of the examples of the iText signature whitepaper at https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/signatures/browse/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures